# Does this simple random variable converge almost surely?

Tags: probability

I was trying to find an example of a simple random variable that converges in probability but not almost surely. I came across this example cited in multiple places:
$$X_n = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{with probability} \ \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 \ \text{with probability} \ \frac{n-1}{n} \end{cases}, \ X = 0$$
It is clear to me that $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X$ but I am having trouble understanding why $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ almost surely. Here is my thought process. I should be able to add some structure to the sample space without changing the problem at all. Suppose the sample space is $[0,1]$ and the probability measure is $P(A) = \int_0^1 \mathbb{1}\{\omega \in A \} d\omega$. Let the underlying structure of the random variables $X_n$ and $X$ be
$$X_n(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if} \ \omega \leq \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 \ \text{if} \ \omega > \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}, \ X(\omega) = 0 $$
Notice how the random variables are still exactly the same, I have just given some explanation about what the underlying mapping might be between states and outcomes. But now that I have defined the variables this way, I have that
$$P(\{\omega: X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)\}) = P(\{\omega: X_n(\omega) \to 0\}) = P(\{\omega: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, \omega > \frac{1}{n} \}) = P((0,1]) = 1$$
So I seem to have proved that $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} X$. There must be some mistake in what I have done but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two scenarios you give are not necessarily the same.  The first scenario **might** be the same as the second, but we cannot tell because you did not specify whether or not the $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ variables are mutually independent. **If these are mutually independent** then you can invoke Borel-Cantelli to prove that, with probability 1, $X_n=1$ for infinitely many indices $n$. So $X_n$ **does not** converge to 0 almost surely.

On the other hand the second scenario is completely specified. There it is clear that the variables are **not mutually independent**, and it is also true, as you say, that the variables **do** converge to 0 almost surely. The proof you gave for that case is correct.

---

Note that you can conclude that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability in the first scenario, even though this scenario is incompletely specified, because convergence in probability to 0 only concerns the individual (marginal) distributions of each $X_n$ and does not require information about how the $X_n$ are related to each other through a joint distribution on $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ for each positive integer $n$.

Comment: Thank you! It did not occur to me to think about whether the $X_n$ were independent. So I guess it is usually assumed that the $X_n$ are independent when this example is given to show the difference between almost sure convergence and convergence in probability. (Sorry cannot upvote because not enough reputation.)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately sometimes the independence assumption is forgotten. It is a crucial assumption.